# Creating a new list out of a dictionary that is sorted based on the values of it

Tags: python, python-2.7

EDIT:

As someone mentioned as comment, dictionaries wont have an order so the question doesn't make sense in this case.

What I need to do instead is to set the order of the items of one list based on index values stored in another list.

For example

> a = [orange,apple,peach,watermelon,gum]
>
> b = [3,4,1,2,0]

In this case, I want to take the values stored in each index in list b and then move the corresponding index in list a to a new index based on that value from list b.

So, with the above example if re-ordered the result would be:

> a = [gum,peach,watermelon,orange,apple]

Since the first item in list b is '3' I need to move the corresponding first value in list a (in this case 'oranges') to that index position of the list, so it moves to position 3. Since '0' is the last element of list 'b' it corresponds to the last element in list 'a' (in this case 'gum'), so the last element of list 'a' should be moved to index position 0, as above.

We can assume that list b will have the same lenght of elements as list a and that the index values will be only in the allowed range (so from 0-4 if we have 5 items) so although a solution that helps solve this would be interesting, it's not needed for this case.

<strike>I have a dictionary, say:</strike>

```
a = {0:3, 1:2, 2:1,3:0}
```

I want to create a list that places the keys of the dictionary on the position specified in the value of the dictionary, in other words the output should be in this case:

```
b = [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or if you have:

```
a = {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2}
```

b should be:

```
b = [1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
```

I read about passing a function to the sort list method but I'm not sure exactly what it needs to be.

Comment: If you need to sort anything, it is the keys of the dictionary. In that case, you don't need any "key" for the `sort()` function.

Comment: `list(a.values())` but note the order may not be as you wish...

Comment: @Chris_Rands If the order isn't as the OP specified then your comment isn't really an answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But dictionaries have no order (prior to Pyton 3.6/7) so the question does not make sense otherwise, unless they want to do some sorting based on the values or the keys (not clear to me)

Comment: @Chris_Rands True, dictionaries do not store the keys nor the values in any particular order. However, that doesn't prevent you from sorting the keys yourself.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You're actually right and thanks for reminding me, the dictionary will need to be changed here as I can't use it for the reason you mentioned.

What I need to do is instead find a way to sort 1 list by index values from another list, assuming that the index values from the second list will be an exact match of the length of the first list.

Comment: @user3647488 I suggest you step away from your computer and describe the steps to solve your problem **in words**. After you figure this out, you can try to translate that solution into python syntax.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've edited the question and described it better so it makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: Since you have almost completely changed your question it probably would make more sense to post it as an entirely new one. Sometimes starting from scratch reduces the potential confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A robust way to do it using a list-comprehension would be:

```
res = [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(max(d) + 1)]
```

which sets the list values of the missing indexes\keys to 0.

---

**Examples**:

```
>> d = {0:1, 1:0, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2}
>> res = [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(max(d) + 1)]
>> res
[1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
```

---

```
>> d = {0:1, 4:2}  # index location 1, 2 & 3 is missing!
>> res = [d.get(i, 0) for i in range(max(d) + 1)]
>> res
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this achieves what I'm looking for but as someone else mentioned and reminded me dictionaries are not ordered so my question wasn't correct..

What I'm looking to do is the following instead:

I have 2 lists:

`a = [0,1,2,3,4]`
`b = [3,2,4,1,0] `

What I want is to sort list `a` in such a manner so that based on the value stored in each  index in `b` the elements in list `a` change their value.

So, if i have a `3` as my first element in the `b` list I want the first item in my `a` list to be moved to the 3rd index value (4th position) of that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list using **list comprehension** if indexes are contiguous.

> Please comment if you are not satisfied with the answer or you are looking for more functionality.
>
> **Note:** Don't forget to see Example 3.1 & 3.2 as these focus on the main part of the problem.

Try the below 2 code examples based on input that you have provided in question.

#### » Example 1

```
a = {0:3, 1:2, 2:1,3:0}
b = [a[value] for value in sorted(a.values()) ]
print(b) # [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

#### » Example 2

```
a= {0:1,1:0,2:4,3:3,4:2}
b = [a[value] for value in sorted(a.values()) ]
print(b) # [1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
```

Now let's focus on another problem.

> We have 2 lists **a** and **b**. We have to rearrange the items of list **a** in accordance to indexes available in list **b**.

#### » Example 3.1 - list of integers

```
a = [10, 21, 52, 63, 74]
b = [3, 2, 4, 1, 0]
d = {} # d = dict()

for indx, value in enumerate(b):
    if(indx != value):
        if indx in d:
            d[value] = a[value]
            a[b[indx]] = d[indx]
            del d[indx]
        else:
            d[value] = a[value]
            a[value] = a[indx]

 print (a) # [74, 63, 21, 10, 52]
```

#### Example 3.2 - list of strings

```
a = ["orange", "apple", "peach", "watermelon", "gum"]
b = [3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
d = dict() # d = {}

for indx, value in enumerate(b):
    if(indx != value):
        if indx in d:
            d[value] = a[value]
            a[b[indx]] = d[indx]
            del d[indx]
        else:
            d[value] = a[value]
            a[value] = a[indx]

print (a) # ['gum', 'peach', 'watermelon', 'orange', 'apple']
```

Comment: what happens if you pass `a = {0:1, 4:2}`

Comment: Yea, that's why I have mentioned that  code is ok for contiguous indexes. Please suggest what value you want you will suggest to fill the missed indexes. `None` or any other.

Comment: I believe that this might work but that perhaps It's not what I'm looking for since dictionaries aren't ordered.

So, how would I do something simillar with 2 lists?

I have:

a = [0,1,2,3,4]
and 
b = [3,2,4,1,0]

I want to basically order a in accordance to b. 

So, if i have a '3' as my first element in the b list I want the first item in my 'a' list to be moved to the 3rd index value (4th position) of that list. Since my second element in list b is a 2 in this case that means that my second element in my first list should come to index position 2 (3rd position) etc.

Comment: Okay got it. Give me little time to update my code. Thanks for explaining properly.

Comment: To clarify a bit :  

 it shouldn't matter what elements I have in list a, list a could be:

a = [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5] or [orange,apple,watermelon,hat,mouse]

It will have a matching number of elements as b and b will have the index values stored.  
  
So if b is b = [3,2,1,0,4] then a should be then re-ordered to a = [hat,watermelon,apple,orange,mouse] .   

If i have a '3' as my first element in the b list I want the first item in my 'a' list to be moved to the 3rd index value (4th position) of that list regardless of what is stored in a.

Comment: **@user3647488**, I have updated my answer with 2 more examples **Example 3.1** & **3.2** which is based on the inputs provided in the above comment. If still there's an issue please let me know. Thanks again to provide inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty list with max value so that it will not give Index error :

```
a = {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2}

values=[0]*(max(a.values())+1)

for i in a:
    values[a[i]]=i
```

output:

```
[1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
```